# wordpress base css file to use between templates?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a base css file somewhere that allows one to keep css changes regardless of template? I have some custom code running on one template, but as soon as I update it or switch it, it will stop working. I was wondering if there is some file where I could keep the changes in permanently.

Comment: In WordPress a template is a php file inside your theme or plugin. Are you asking about a CSS file wich would apply regardless the origin of the Theme installed?

Comment: No, but you could create a [site-specific plugin](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/what-why-and-how-tos-of-creating-a-site-specific-wordpress-plugin/) and have it enqueue your custom CSS stylesheet always.